# Replace a font style inside tag <Text>

Tags: react-native

Hello i want to replace a font style inside `<Text>`, 
this assumption variable x is dynamic variable.

for example :

> when x="Hell" => **Hell**oooo
>   when x="He" => **He**lloooo
>   when x="lloooo" => He**lloooo**

I tried with this code :

```
render() {
  var x = "Hell"; // Hell/He/lloooo
  var myOldString = "Helloooo";
  var reg = new RegExp(x, "g");
  var myNewString = myOldString.replace(reg, `<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>${x}</Text>`);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{myNewString}</Text>
    </View>
  );}
```

But the result is just an ordinary string :

```
   when x="Hell" => <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Hell</Text>ooo
   when x="He" => <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>He</Text>llooo
   when x="lloooo" => He<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>lloooo</Text>
```

How to render a string inside `<Text>`, in order to be nested `<Text>`, not the ordinary string ?

Answer (score 1):

this was a deceptively simple question, after much tinkering I think I have something for you.

This may not be the most efficient/elegant approach, but it worked when I tested it.

First you'll need 2 state values

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textToBold:'ell',
      myArr:[],
    };
  };
```

One to keep a reference to the parts you are trying to bold and another to keep an array after we split the string.

Next, to fill 'myArr' with values will be done so via this code; all of which takes place at componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount() {
    var reg = new RegExp(this.state.textToBold); //builds a RegExp from what you are trying to bold
    var myOldString = "Helloooo"
    var res = myOldString.split(reg); //splits the original string based on regex match
    this.setState({
        myArr: res //now you have an array of all remaining values
    })
  }
```

Finally in your render method, include a way to generate Components dynamically based on the array.

```
 render() {
    let result = this.state.myArr.map((a, i) => {
      if ( i > 0) {
      return (
        <Text key={i}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.textToBold}</Text>{ a }
        </Text>
      )
    } else { //Case to accommodate for extra repeating values
      return (<Text key={i}>{ a }</Text>)
    }
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          { result }
        </Text>
     </View>
    )
 }
```

So now to "highlight" whatever text you want, you just change the state value, 'textToBold'.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with [Markdown](https://github.com/CharlesMangwa/react-native-simple-markdown)

Try this code :

```
render() {
  var x = "Hell"; // Hell/He/lloooo
  var myOldString = "Helloooo";
  var reg = new RegExp(x, "g");
  var myNewString = myOldString.replace(reg, `**${x}**`);
  return (
    <View>
      <Markdown>{myNewString}</Markdown>
    </View>
  );}
```